# Linux as router, bandwith degradation when using IPv6

Tags: linux, routing, ipv6, router, nat

I have a Linux 3.1.6 kernel as a router on a server with two CPUs Xeon E5405.
The machine have two 1 Gbps network interfaces (Ethernet).
We have several networks, two of them are `10.0.0.0/20`, `10.1.0.0/20`.

When copying a file between two machines in the same network I have about 1 Gbps copying speed, but when copying between networks the speed degrades to ~200 Mbps. Copying to/from the outside world yield the same speed (~200 Mbps), but it should be much more, we have about ~1 Gbps to the outside and servers nearby with high available download speeds (confirmed, tested).
So the problem is the routing server (we also did several tests confirming this).

What could be the problem? Can the NAT process be this slow, routing between networks is slow, CPUs aren't to busy (load is negligible), kernel bug?

**HAH, UPDATE (17:40):**
I discovered that this is IPv6 issue somehow. How?
`wget SERVER_NETWORK1_IPv4/file` (~1 Gbps)
`wget SERVER_NETWORK2_IPv4/file` (~1 Gbps)
`wget **SERVER_DNS_NAME**/file` **(~200 Mbps with DNS name)** HA!
`wget SERVER_IPv6/file` **(~200 Mbps with IPv6 address)** HA!

So, a different question, why IPv6 is multiple times slower?

Comment: A few possibilities: interrupt contention, bus contention, crappy switch, crappy NICs, crappy drivers for the NICs, etc.  Probably interrupt contention.

Comment: Nope, switches are new enterprise grade HP 10Gbps, connected with OM3 grade cabling (short distances). Copying in the same network (no router in between) gives full port capabilities, almost 1 Gbps copying speed for workstaions connected to 1000T ports.

Comment: "Probably interrupt contention." As in, your NICs aren't offloading the interrupts (either because the drivers don't tell them to, or because you have an interrupt conflict).

Comment: Is it slow only when forwarding between the two networks, or also when you transfer from/to the router itself?

Comment: Hah, I discovered that this might be internetwork problem. I can transfer files using both IPv4 and IPv6 fast, but internetwork transfers using IPv6 are slow. It is interesting that IPv4 transfer is slower when using different networks, but not as drastic as with IPv6.

Comment: Why do you have such an old kernel?

Comment: That is a long story, but now it is not the time for upgrade :)